# Ajax onevent is not firing on IE11

Tags: ajax, jsf-2, internet-explorer-11

I have the following code. I's a date imput text.

```
<td class="plAnchoFijoIzq">
<h:inputText id="reqFentPR" maxlength="10" 
    value="#{proyectoEditar.pry.reqFentPR}" 
    onchange="fechaModif(this.id)" 
    readonly="#{!empty proyectoEditar.pry.reqFentR or proyectoEditar.modoConsulta}" 
    size="12" 
    styleClass="#{!empty proyectoEditar.pry.reqFentR or proyectoEditar.modoConsulta? 'divPlanificacionDesactivado': (proyectoEditar.pry.reqFentPRCorrecta ? 'divPlanificacionNormal datepicker fechaSlash' : 'divPlanificacionRojo datepicker fechaSlash')}"        
    converterMessage="El valor de la fecha de Entrega Requerimientos no es correcto"    
    onfocus="setIdFocus(this.id)">
    <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd/MM/yyyy"/>
    <f:ajax  onevent="ocultarLoadingAjaxPlanificacion"  event="change" render="reqFentA indicador @all" execute ="@form" /> 
</h:inputText></td>
```

His is ocultarLoadingAjaxPlanificacion code:

```
function ocultarLoadingAjaxPlanificacion(data){
   console.log("Dentro ocultar loading")
   var idElemento = data.source.id;
   if (data.status === 'complete') {
      console.log("complete");
      ocultarLoading();
   }else if (data.status === 'begin') {
      console.log("Begin");
      mostrarLoading();
      verificarEstados();
   } else if (data.status == 'success') {
      console.log("Success");
      obtenerSiguienteFocusPlanif(idElemento);
  }
```

}

In chrome and firefox all works fine, but in IE11 whith this configuration doesn't fire onevent function.
[image: IE11 emulation]

I need it to work with this configuration. what am I doing wrong?
Thank you in advance

Comment: does it give any error in the console? The above code is not giving any idea about the issue. If you get any error then please try to share the error information that may help to get some idea about the issue.

Comment: Thank you for your response. No. It doesn't give any error in the console.

Comment: I try to search for the issue and found that IE has some issues while using f:ajax tags. I noticed that people are suggesting to bind the event using JS or jquery. Not sure whether this is a suitable option for you. I suggest you contact the Ajax support to know their opinion on this issue. I did not get any other solution.